# Make DIV load CSS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For the program I'm writing I have a main navigation page where the user get landed after he / she log into the system.

On this screen I use 2 DIV's one div is for the navigation bar second one is used as an iFrame.

I'm using w3.css library to create the navigation bar but this actually mess up my CSS main CSS file when I load the target file in the second div. But it works fine if I use an iFrame which I really don't like to do.

If I could load my CSS file when the div loads the target link file the problem will be solved.

So my problem is how to load the CSS file in to the div when the external file loads.

This is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Time Sheet</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Style Sheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/main.css">


<!-- Java Scripts -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/navBar.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/fileLoader.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>
<div class="w3-bar w3-light-gray w3-card-4" style="z-index: 991">
<a href="listUser.php" target="container" id="main" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-light-blue">Home</a>
<a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-light-blue">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-light-blue">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-light-blue w3-right">Link 3</a>
</div>
<div id="My-container">
<!--  All pages load here  -->
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

My NavBar JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#main').click(function () {
        $('#My-container').load('listUser.php');
    })

});
```

File loader JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($("#my-container").size>0){
        if (document.createStyleSheet){
            document.createStyleSheet('../../CSS/main.css');
        }
        else {
            $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' href='../../CSS/main.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />"));
        }
    }
});
```

Above file loader function is not mine I found it on a site and tried to use it but when I do console throws an error saying "Size" is not a function. When I change it to length the error goes away but code doesn't work.

If any one asks why don't you just copy paste the nav bar to all the files my answer is I'm lazy.

Any way please show me the light.

Comment: so you want to load the css along with the file that loads in the iframe ie. `listUser.php`?

Comment: @ImmortalDude Yes it's the same CSS linked to the main page but it doesn't take effect inside the **div**. I'm not using iFrames.

Comment: can you see CSS file being loaded on the network tab in dev tools? Also... a bonus question: EDIT: why are you adding main.css when you already have it in index.html??

Comment: As a side comment. If something looks and feels over-engineered, it probably is...

Comment: then simply append the styles to the main document

Comment: @VladimirM the main page does has both the CSS files and when checked both main.css and w3.css do get called and get loaded but main.css doesn't take effect when listUser.php get loaded in to the "my-continer" div.

Comment: @ImmortalDude I did try it using that file loader javascript but it's not working I really can't figure this out.

Comment: @Sand yes. I just noticed that you already have main.css in index.html. I'd guess that you have problem with your CSS definition. Can you show it?

Comment: @VladimirM I did check my CSS against w3.css both differs I really don't know why is this happening.

Comment: If you post the rendered source code, it may be easier to understand where the issues stems. If the css is already loaded and new elements are added to the DOM that use this css, they will inherit the styles. You don't need to load the css file after the new data is loaded.

Comment: You need my source from the browser right ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to check if that specific dom exist or not. For that you need to use `length`. Also the dom id seems to be `My-container` but not `my-container`.

You can try the following

```
if($("#My-container").length>0){
// rest of the code
}
```